# How to fit CAShape Layer to UIImage View?

Tags: swift, core-animation, cashapelayer, swiftsvg, pocketsvg

I am parsing SVG image file and convert it paths into CAShapeLayer, after that I am adding this CAShapeLayer to UIImage View's layer.
It's work fine, but the problem is that it does not fit to the UIImage View.
That's output.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4rqm.png).
That's code of adding layers to UIImageView

```
        if let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "svg") {
        let paths = SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: svgURL)
        for path in paths {
            items.append(path)
            let layer = createLayer(path: path)
            layer.frame = self.backgroundIV.bounds
            self.backgroundIV.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }
        
        
    }   // Create Layer from Paths Method


    fileprivate func createLayer(path: SVGBezierPath) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    if let any = path.svgAttributes["stroke"] {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = (any as! CGColor)
    }
    
    if let any = path.svgAttributes["fill"] {
        shapeLayer.fillColor = (any as! CGColor)
    }
    return shapeLayer
}
```

I Searched and added these two lines of code, i got this result

```
let scale = CGFloat(0.5) 
        for path in paths {
            path.apply(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
            items.append(path)
            let layer = createLayer(path: path)
            layer.frame = self.backgroundIV.bounds
            self.backgroundIV.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }
```

That's is output.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b7lN.png)

I don't know how to calculate `scaleX` or `scaleY` (using in `CGAffineTransform` method) value according to uiImage View bounds

**Edit**
Note: I am apply touch support to CAShapeLayer,
That's code.

```
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.backgroundIV),
              let layers = self.backgroundIV.layer.sublayers
        else { return }
        var hitLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []
        selectedLayer?.lineWidth = CGFloat(0)
        for subLayer in layers {
            if let thisLayer = subLayer as? CAShapeLayer,
               let pth = thisLayer.path {
                let layerPoint: CGPoint = thisLayer.convert(point, from: self.backgroundIV.layer)
                if pth.contains(layerPoint) {
//                    undoModel.append()
                    hitLayers.append(thisLayer)
                }
            }
        }
        
        selectedLayer = hitLayers.last
        selectedLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        selectedLayer?.lineWidth = CGFloat(3)
        undo.append(.init(stokeColor: nil, selectedLayer: selectedLayer, points: []))
        
        if ((selectedLayer?.frame.contains(point)) != nil) {
            isDragged = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not because the size you are checking: `self.backgroundIV.bounds` is not the final one. Or it is? Could you print it and check that? If it's not the final one, check layoutSubviews, and update the layer frame/scale there.

Comment: I belive you are using PocketSVG, then better to use provided SVGImageView.

Comment: @ChanOnly123 It does not work in my case.

Comment: @AliAkbar - assuming you're using `PocketSVG` (based on your previous question), is there a reason you're not using its `SVGImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your updated question, calculating scale using view bounds

```
var paths = [SVGBezierPath]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Freesample", withExtension: "svg") {
        paths = SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: svgURL)
        backgroundIV.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3).cgColor
        backgroundIV.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let svgBounds = SVGBoundingRectForPaths(paths)
    var scale = CGFloat.zero
    if backgroundIV.bounds.width < backgroundIV.bounds.height {
        scale = backgroundIV.bounds.width / svgBounds.width
    } else {
        scale = backgroundIV.bounds.height / svgBounds.height
    }
    
    self.backgroundIV.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    for path in paths {
        path.apply(.init(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
        let layer = createLayer(path: path)
        layer.frame = self.backgroundIV.bounds
        self.backgroundIV.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
It work but i forgot to tell that I am apply touch support to layers so, UIImage will not handle it.

Comment: Thanks, that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same answer I gave you to your previous question about detecting touches on multiple layers.

The difference is, instead of using your code to create/add the layers, this example uses `SVGImageView` which is part of `PocketSVG`:

```
class BoxesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var backgroundIV: SVGImageView!
    
    var detectMode: DetectMode = .All
    var detectType: DetectType = .ShapePath
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        guard let svgURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "roundedboxes", withExtension: "svg") else {
            fatalError("SVG file not found!!!")
        }
        
        backgroundIV = SVGImageView.init(contentsOf: svgURL)
        
        backgroundIV.frame = view.bounds
        backgroundIV.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        backgroundIV.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        
        let modeControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["All", "Top Most", "Bottom Most"])
        let typeControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Shape Path", "Shape Bounding Box"])
        
        modeControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        typeControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        backgroundIV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(modeControl)
        view.addSubview(typeControl)
        view.addSubview(backgroundIV)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            modeControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            modeControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            modeControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            typeControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: modeControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            typeControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            typeControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            backgroundIV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: typeControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            backgroundIV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            backgroundIV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            backgroundIV.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundIV.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        modeControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(modeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        typeControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(typeChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        modeControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        typeControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        
        // so we can see the frame of the image view
        backgroundIV.backgroundColor = .white
        
    }
    
    @objc func modeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) -> Void {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            detectMode = .All
        case 1:
            detectMode = .TopMost
        case 2:
            detectMode = .BottomMost
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func typeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) -> Void {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            detectType = .ShapePath
        case 1:
            detectType = .ShapeBounds
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func createLayer(path: SVGBezierPath) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        if let any = path.svgAttributes["stroke"] {
            shapeLayer.strokeColor = (any as! CGColor)
        }
        
        if let any = path.svgAttributes["fill"] {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = (any as! CGColor)
        }
        return shapeLayer
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self.backgroundIV),
              // make sure backgroundIV has sublayers
              let layers = self.backgroundIV.layer.sublayers
        else { return }
        
        var hitLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []
        
        // loop through all sublayers
        for subLayer in layers {
            // make sure
            //  it is a CAShapeLayer
            //  it has a path
            if let thisLayer = subLayer as? CAShapeLayer,
               let pth = thisLayer.path {
                // clear the lineWidth... we'll reset it after getting the hit layers
                thisLayer.lineWidth = 0
                
                // convert touch point from backgroundIV.layer to thisLayer
                let layerPoint: CGPoint = thisLayer.convert(point, from: self.backgroundIV.layer)
                
                if detectType == .ShapePath {
                    // does the path contain the point?
                    if pth.contains(layerPoint) {
                        hitLayers.append(thisLayer)
                    }
                } else if detectType == .ShapeBounds {
                    if pth.boundingBox.contains(layerPoint) {
                        hitLayers.append(thisLayer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if detectMode == .All {
            hitLayers.forEach { layer in
                layer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
                layer.lineWidth = 3
            }
        } else if detectMode == .TopMost {
            if let layer = hitLayers.last {
                layer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
                layer.lineWidth = 3
            }
        } else if detectMode == .BottomMost {
            if let layer = hitLayers.first {
                layer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
                layer.lineWidth = 3
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Now the SVG file is scaled to fit the view:

[image]